# How to avoid parameter reference/substitution in tags and UDT

Tags: ignition, scada-ignition

I would like to put a short JSON string in a memory tag but am getting an error: "Error expanding potential parameter reference in tag" due to the { in the JSON initiating parameter substitution. I've tried a few simple escapes such as \{, \\{ and {{, no joy.

How can I turn this off within the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ignition 7.9.2, despite the word "error", this is merely a *warning* that the JSON can't be interpreted as a substitution.  This warning can be ignored unless you are attempting parameter substitution.

I spoke with Ignition support, they said there is no way to avoid this warning, but that they may make improvements here to enable substitution in JSON in a future release.